# How to get max and min value in stack C#

Tags: c#, methods, stack, max, min

How can I get the max and min value in the stack using C#?

I searched about that a lot I didn't find any way that can help me with it.

I'm using Visual Studio and created a form to enter numbers in a stack. But I have no idea how to get the max number and min number in that stack

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: do you mean a `Stack` object?

Comment: Stack my_stack = new Stack(): 
using this one @pm100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
        // load demo stack
        var s = new Stack<int>();
        s.Push(1);
        s.Push(2);
        s.Push(3);
```

now

```
        var minn = s.Min(); <<<==== get min
        var maxx = s.Max(); <<<=== get max
```

explanation

A `Stack` is an `IEnumerable` type so all LINQ extensions can be used on it

PS - note that you should not use the old `Stack` class, use `Stack<int>`;  your comment suggested that you were using `Stack`

Comment: how i can use this with textbox so the textbox letting user entering the number to stack like this one
            number.Push(textBox1.Text);
            listBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);

Comment: @MohamadAlkousi - my Pushes above were just example, you can push numbers into the stack however you like, The last 2 lines are the important ones

Comment: really thanks for help, it really worked, the only issue i got that I can't push using textbox at all, It doesn't accept textbox.

Comment: @MohamadAlkousi thats because a textbox is text not an int. You need `Int32.Parse`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Stack<int> numbers...
int minNum = numbers.ToArray().Min();
int maxNum = numbers.ToArray().Max();
```